# Letting user chose which image a button has?

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, imagebutton

I´m new to coding and I´ve created a game with a black button in the main class. I want to create a setting class where the user can click on a blue button to change the black button in the main class or on a red button to change the black button in the main class to red.

Here is the main class:

```
class Mainclass: SKScene{

 var gameButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blackDot") //current button image
}
```

Here is the setting class:

```
class Settings: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

let blueButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueDot") //button to select 
blueButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.2, y: self.size.height * 0.8)
blueButton.setScale(0.53)
self.addChild(blueButton)

let redButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redDot") //button to select 
redButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.4, y: self.size.height * 0.8)
redButton.setScale(0.53)
self.addChild(redButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches{

    let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

    if atPoint(locationUser) == blueButton {

    //Change the button image in the Mainclass from black to blue if user tap on blueButton

    }

    if atPoint(locationUser) == redButton {

    //Change the button image in the Mainclass from black to red if user tap on redButton

    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: So you want to have two scenes, one would be the actual game, and other would be a Settings screen? If so, you can use user defaults to save settings (eg. which image is going to be used in a game scene). You can try, and if you are still stuck, I can make an example for you, just let me know.

Comment: Yes, I want to have two different screens. An example would be great @Whirlwind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have two scenes, called `GameScene.swift` and `SettingsScene.swift` and corresponding `.sks` files called `GameScene.sks` and `SettingsScene.sks`. Also we have three images, called `default_button`, `purple_button` and `blue_button` (stored in our `.xcassets` folder).

Here is the `SettingsScene.swift`:

```
import SpriteKit

class SettingsScene: SKScene {

    var purpleButton = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "purple_button")
    var blueButton = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "blue_button")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = .purple

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) {

            if purpleButton.contains(location) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set("purple_button", forKey: "button")
            }else if blueButton.contains(location){

                UserDefaults.standard.set("blue_button", forKey: "button")
            }else{

                if let mainScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

                    //transition to Settings scene
                    self.view?.presentScene(mainScene)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This scene has two buttons, and when a user tap on one of them, we will remember which one is tapped by storing appropriate image name in user defaults, for example:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set("purple_button", forKey: "button")
```

Later on we will read from a persistent storage (in `GameScene` `didMoveTo:view` method) and use what is found there.

Also, user defaults are not erased when app is closed by the user, so next time the a user launches the app, he will have his settings saved and ready to use.

So after selecting one of the buttons from the `Settings` scene, and transitioning to the GameScene, you will your button set to whatever you have previously chosen. Here is the `GameScene`:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

    let button = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "default_button")
    override  func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        if let buttonImageName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "button") {

            //set what is found in settings
            button.texture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: buttonImageName)
        }
        backgroundColor = .white
        addChild(button)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) {

            if button.contains(location) {

            }else{
                if let settingScene = SettingsScene(fileNamed:"SettingsScene") {

                    //transition to Settings scene
                    self.view?.presentScene(settingScene)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. Is there a way that the first button is always black(that means if the user first downloads the app and presses play without changing the button it will be black)@Whirlwind

Comment: First time that app launches , if nothing is saved in defaults, the button will have a default image. Related line (from `GameScene`) : `let button = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "default_button")`.